# SSH can't use internet when multiple interfaces present in route

Tags: ssh, route

I'm trying to make SSH tunnel connection on any possible interface (which has internet connection).

I'm currently using `ppp0` and `eth0` interfaces. `ppp0` always has internet and reinitialized if connection is lost. `eth0`'s IP is assigned via DHCP and never has internet connection.

If I reboot the PC, a default route via `eth0` is added to routing table. If that occurs, I can `ping` to Google but can't connect to remote SSH server.

If I unplug `eth0` cable, everything works as expected. If I replug the cable, everything still works correctly.

As a workaround, I wrote a script which deletes all default routes using device `eth0`.

So why is `ping`, `telnet`, `apt-get` etc. can use internet but SSH can't?

Comment: Sure eth0 has no Internet?

Comment: Yes, sure. 
[code]
    ping -I eth0 -c 5 google.com
    PING google.com (173.194.39.230) from 10.0.0.136 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
    From 10.0.0.136 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.0.0.136 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.0.0.136 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.0.0.136 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
    From 10.0.0.136 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: Try `traceroute -n www.google.com`

Comment: `sudo traceroute -i eth0 -n www.google.com 
[sudo] password for ceremcem: 
traceroute to www.google.com (173.194.39.241), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
...28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *`

Comment: Try ping, traceroute and tcptraceroute to port 22 (don't force eth0).